# Show bindfs target

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

When creating a FUSE mount:

```
bindfs -u joe -g users -r /files /home/joe/files
```

After the mount is done, what command can I use to see the target?
Eg, how can I see that /home/joe/files points to /files?

None of the following reveals any useful information:

```
root@server:/# cat /proc/mounts | grep files
bindfs /home/joe/files fuse.bindfs ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0

root@server:/# findmnt | grep files
...
└─/home/joe/files bindfs fuse.bindfs ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other

root@server:/# mount | grep files
bindfs on /home/joe/files type fuse.bindfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

Comment: What OS are you using ? In Debian 10 Buster `findmnt` shows the target.